# How to return the leftmost node of AVL tree in O(1) time?

Tags: data-structures, avl-tree

My idea is:

```
    AVLNode minOfTree(AVLNode node) {
        while (node.left != null) node = node.left;
    return node;
    }
```

However, a while loop can't be O(1) time right?

Comment: You can't do this in a standard AVL tree, but if you want to be able to return the left-most node in O(1) time, then you could augment the tree by adding a pointer from each node to its left-most node, as long as you make sure to keep these pointers updated when you insert or remove nodes.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to find the smallest value with pointers like you said. I felt like it still requires traverse.

Comment: Uh, if each node contains a pointer to the left-most node in its subtree then the `minOfSubtree` method simply returns that pointer. The hard part is making sure those pointers always point in the right places.

Comment: ah I got it. In the first time, I thought you mean add a pointer from each node to the node's leftmost node. But you actually meant to the tree's leftmost node. My bad. Thank you!

Comment: The subtree's left-most node, not necessarily the whole tree.

Comment: Why the subtree's, my purpose is to return the smallest value of the tree. I thought it should be the whole tree.

Comment: Then why is your method called `minOfSubtree`?

Comment: ah sorry, my bad. edited.

Comment: OK, in that case only the tree's root node (or perhaps a wrapper object representing the whole tree) needs to maintain a pointer to the tree's left-most node.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  It takes O(log N) time to walk from the root to the left-most node.

So, just keep a pointer the the left-most node around.  Whenever you delete it or insert a smaller node, just find the left-most node again.  Insert and delete both take O(log N) time already, so you can spend an additional O(log N) time without changing their complexity.